# java-server websocket failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, server

I am learning to create the web socket server in java with tomcat,

but when I run the tomcat9.0 with the sample code,

I always get the below error in the chrome developer tool response.

```
 **web socket failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404**
```

I query the much the reference, I still not resolve the problem,

I am use the tomcat9.0 & jre 1.8.0, and I refer the [blog](https://www.pegaxchange.com/2018/01/28/websocket-server-java/).

I create the server code(project -> new -> Servlet file)  is

```
 package idv.yu;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import javax.websocket.OnClose;
 import javax.websocket.OnError;
 import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
 import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
 import javax.websocket.Session;
 import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

 @ServerEndpoint(value = "/endpoint")
 public class MyWebsocket {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("onOpen::" + session.getId());
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        System.out.println("onClose::" + session.getId());
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        System.out.println("onMessage::From=" + session.getId() + "      Message=" + message);

        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello Client " +      session.getId() + "!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("onError::" + t.getMessage());
    }
 }
```

My project tree structure is below:

[image]

In my chrome developer tool I set the code

```
 class WebSocketClient {

     constructor(protocol, hostname, port, endpoint) {

         this.webSocket = null;

    this.protocol = protocol;
    this.hostname = hostname;
    this.port     = port;
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
}

getServerUrl() {
    return this.protocol + "://" + this.hostname + ":" + this.port + this.endpoint;
}

connect() {
    try {
        this.webSocket = new WebSocket(this.getServerUrl());

        // 
        // Implement WebSocket event handlers!
        //
        this.webSocket.onopen = function(event) {
            console.log('onopen::' + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
        }

        this.webSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
            var msg = event.data;
            console.log('onmessage::' + JSON.stringify(msg, null, 4));
        }
        this.webSocket.onclose = function(event) {
            console.log('onclose::' + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));                
             }
             this.webSocket.onerror = function(event) {
                 console.log('onerror::' + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
             }

         } catch (exception) {
             console.error(exception);
         }
     }

     getStatus() {
         return this.webSocket.readyState;
     }
     send(message) {

         if (this.webSocket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
             this.webSocket.send(message);

         } else {
             console.error('webSocket is not open. readyState=' + this.webSocket.readyState);
         }
     }
     disconnect() {
         if (this.webSocket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
             this.webSocket.close();

         } else {
             console.error('webSocket is not open. readyState=' + this.webSocket.readyState);
         }
     }
 }
```

the last I set the command below:

```
 var client = new WebSocketClient('ws', '127.0.0.1', 8080, '/WebsocketDemo/endpoint');
 client.connect();
```

But I get the error:

[image]

Have anyone known how to resolve the problem?

should the "web.xml" had to set any something?

my web.xml is default value, and I had check the project have websocket-api.jar file in the library.
[image]

Thank you very much.

-- edit--

my WebContent/Web-INF/web.xml content below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"      xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"      version="3.1">
   <display-name>WebsocketDemo</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
 </web-app>
```

Comment: Show the web.xml contents

Comment: @JimGarrison I had supplement the web.xml content in the edit, please. thank you.

Comment: As Sepehr GH mentioned, it may be linked to the deployment path: what is the contextroot of your application?

Comment: @Al1 I run the code method is right click on the 'MyWebsocket.java' file -> select 'run as' ->'run on server'.

Comment: @dickfala and what url appears on your browser? `http://localhost:XXXX/WebsocketDemo/` ?

Comment: @Al1 my url is http://localhost:8080/WebsocketDemo/  is show HTTP Status 404 – Not Found, I have not build the html page, just build the java(servelet file). (thank your of response my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was resolved the problem,

Going to the eclipse →　Project → build automatically checked the item,

My project is running correct evertime.

Using the websocket is not to put other jar file, the tomcat8,9 have websocket jar in lib folder.

thank @sepehr GH,@Al1

Answer (score 1):

`404` in websocket is not any different from `404` in HTTP, it means the address you are trying to reach can not be found on the server. In your case I think its about `/WebsocketDemo` part. The `/endpoint` is available in your endpoint configuration but its missing `/WebsocketDemo`. Perhaps you should deploy your WAR under `/WebsocketDemo` in webapps, or remove this part of the address.

Comment: I use three PC try to build the same procedure, Or try to add the java-websocket-1.3.8.jar file in to the lib folder, but sometime the connect is correct, sometimes is fault with error 404. I think is it the websocket jar file dependency problem? But I don't known how to resolve...Orz..

Comment: @dickfala to be more clear, I meant you have to use the war file you deploy under `/websocketDemo` in tomcat, otherwise you have to remove `/websocketDemo` from your address  `var client = new WebSocketClient('ws', '127.0.0.1', 8080, '/endpoint');`. Would you do second one and tell me the result?

Comment: , I  remove /websocketDemo from my address, the result is same error (WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/endpoint' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404). Sorry , I don't known the where the war file to use~ (thank your of response my question.).